# How to get position of Radiobutton using PDFbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Hello i am using this code for getting position of components in PDF. But if field is type Radiobutton then fieldAreaArray = null

```
COSDictionary fieldDict = field.getCOSObject();
COSArray fieldAreaArray = (COSArray) fieldDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.RECT);

            float left = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(0)).doubleValue();              
            float bottom = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(1)).doubleValue();
            float right = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(2)).doubleValue();
            float top = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(3)).doubleValue();
```

Comment: You have to be aware that there is a difference in pdfs between the form field and its visualisations aka widgets. If a form field has only a single visualisation, the pdf object modeling the form field and the pdf object modeling the visualisation can be merged into a single object. Only in such a merged situation your code works. A radio button form field, on the other hand, hardly ever has only one widget as the form field represents the state of the whole connected group of radio buttons.

Comment: @Tomm23 the best is to have a look at the file with PDFDebugger. Change to "show internal structure" and then look at Root/AcroForm/Fields . Re the widgets, get your field and then call `getWidgets()` and then get the rectangles from each widget (there's a direct method). For example, the radio button (which look like checkmarks, but these are really radio buttons) in the file in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-142 has 9 widgets, see in `Root/AcroForm/Fields/[9]/Kids`.

Comment: @Tomm23 Have Tilman's and my comment helped you? If yes, it would be nice if you created an actual answer to your question describing your solution. If no, what specifically did you not understand?

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Yes your anser helped me. When field instance of  JRadiobutton is`s group of RadioButtons and getWidgets() have position of all buttons in group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field can have several widgets (a radio button certainly will, see the comment by mkl below the question) and then the widget list will be found in the /Kids array, so make your life easy and use the methods provided by PDFBox instead of accessing the dictionary directly. The attached code works with the file from the [PDFBOX-142](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-142) issue. The field "amt", although it looks like a checkmark, is radio button field with 9 widgets - run [PDFDebugger](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x) and go to the "View" menu, and change to "show internal structure" and then look at Root/AcroForm/Fields:

[image]

To get the rectangles programmatically, use this code:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new URL("https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12742551/Testformular1.pdf").openStream());
PDField field = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("amt");
System.out.println(field.getClass().getSimpleName());
for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : field.getWidgets())
{
    System.out.println(widget.getRectangle());
}
document.close();
```

And this is the output:

```
PDRadioButton
[177.944,580.3095,190.1991,592.0744]
[178.8963,350.25168,191.45924,361.8096]
[535.79285,467.17078,548.0479,478.93567]
[417.16348,467.17078,429.41858,478.93567]
[298.04395,466.19037,310.29904,477.95526]
[177.944,466.19037,190.1991,477.95526]
[534.81244,581.2899,547.0675,593.0548]
[417.16348,581.2899,429.41858,593.0548]
[298.04395,581.2899,310.29904,593.0548]
```

You can verify these positions by opening the file with PDFDebugger (if already opened in "show internal structure" mode, then in the "View" menu choose "show pages") and move your mouse on the rendered image, the coordinates will be shown at the bottom left of the main frame.